# Help installing ubuntu alongside windows?

Tags: dual-boot

Ok, so I have installed the iso file for ubuntu on a flash drive.  I would like to keep windows on my computer and use the dual boot feature.  However, I am open to getting rid of windows altogether if I can get to ubuntu.

My issue is that I can't even get into the BIOS.  My computer just skips everything and automatically logs into a windows 7 user account.  I have tried repeatedly pressing every function key and escape and delete, but when I do this the computer just goes into some limbo mode.  The monitor doesn't light up and nothing happens.  While in this limbo mode, pressing the power button will instantly turn off the computer, when usually you can hear it power down.

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: I think you should ask this question in [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2):

1. If you're having trouble getting in to your computer's BIOS setup utility, visit [BIOS Setup Utility Access Keys for Popular Computer Systems](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/biosaccess_pc.htm).
2. If you can't find your computer system in the list, the <kbd>Del</kbd> key is frequently used to access the BIOS setup utility. I've also noticed a trend in BIOS/UEFI these days to hide the text instructing you on which key to press, until you press any key.
3. If the BIOS setup utility access key doesn't work, try spamming the key repeatedly as soon as you see the manufacturer's splash screen when the computer is booting.
4. There is a setting in some BIOSs called *Fast boot* or something like that. It might have toggled off due to low battery causing a reset. This may also explain why the BIOS boot menu is no longer accessible.
5. If your manufacturer's boot screen doesn't show, it wouldn't hurt to change your motherboard's CMOS battery (it looks like a silver coin) and it might help.

   [image]

Comment: That is what I have been doing.  I have tried spamming it.  And I don't ever see any screen.  It goes from black to logged into windows.  Nothing else is even visible.